# set a panel in background and another in foregroud

Tags: java, swing

I'have a little problem for my group project, in this project we must make a game. I have 2 panel one for the background with the map (created from a json) and another panel with the character. I 'have tried with jlayeredpane but the map is not centered in my jframe. I've also tried with .setOpaque(true/false)  but it's doesn't work.
anyone have an Idea ?

here is my code :

```
package vue;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import org.json.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import controler.abstractControler;

import observer.Observer;

public class gamingArea extends JPanel implements Observer {
    private String ressourcesImg = "resources/images/";
    private Hashtable <String,String> tile = new Hashtable();
    private abstractControler controler;
    private JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    private JSONArray map ;

    private JPanel centerPanel,topPanel,playerPanel,mapPanel,centerContentPanel;

    private GridBagLayout centerLayout,topLayout;
    private GridLayout mapLayout,playerLayout;
    private BorderLayout divider;
    private JLabel banniereLabel;
    private BufferedImage banniere;

    public gamingArea(abstractControler controler) {
        this.controler = controler;
        //getting the image from system file
        try {
            banniere = ImageIO.read(new File(ressourcesImg+"banniere.png"));
            banniereLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(banniere));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            banniereLabel = new JLabel();
            banniereLabel.setText("error file can't be read");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //getting the map in json format
        try {
            map = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("resources/cartes/carte.json"))).get("boite");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //init Jpanel
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        playerPanel = new JPanel();
        mapPanel = new JPanel();
        centerContentPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        //init layout
        centerLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        topLayout = new GridBagLayout();

        divider = new BorderLayout();

        playerLayout = new GridLayout(map.size(),map.size());
        mapLayout = new GridLayout(map.size(),map.size());


        //setting layout
        this.setLayout(divider);
        centerPanel.setLayout(centerLayout);
        topPanel.setLayout(topLayout);
        mapPanel.setLayout(mapLayout);
        playerPanel.setLayout(playerLayout);


        //setting the hasmap
        tile.put("1",ressourcesImg+"sol.png");
        tile.put("2",ressourcesImg+"mur.png");

        //defining layout which show the map        
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<String> line= (ArrayList<String>) map.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {
                try {
                    BufferedImage tempBuf = ImageIO.read(new File(tile.get(line.get(j))));
                    JLabel temp =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tempBuf));
                    mapPanel.add(temp);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        //adding a player sample
        BufferedImage testb;
        try {
            testb = ImageIO.read(new File(ressourcesImg+"snake_tete_invisible.png"));
            JLabel test =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon(testb));
            playerPanel.add(test);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //setting panels opaque or not
        mapPanel.setOpaque(true);
        playerPanel.setOpaque(false);
        //adding components to main panels 
        //centerContentPanel.add(mapPanel);
        //centerContentPanel.add(playerPanel);
        centerPanel.add(centerContentPanel);
        topPanel.add(banniereLabel);
        this.add(topPanel,divider.PAGE_START);
        this.add(mapPanel,divider.CENTER);
        this.add(playerPanel,divider.CENTER);       
    }
    @Override
    public void update(String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void changePanel(String nomPanel) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```

Comment: We don't own the images nor the JSON to replicate the issue. Please create and post a proper [mcve] that shows your issue. In this case you might try with a simple `JPanel` override its [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method  in which you'll paint the map image, then add another `JPanel` over it where you paint the image, and call over this second `JPanel` the `setOpaque(false);` method.

Comment: You are adding a panel to `CENTER` position twice. At the bottom of your code. Is that a typo made when copy pasting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, so for those who want to know here the solution to make a tile map without library in Java : create your map with a Json like that :

```
{"box":[
       ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"]
       ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"]
       ]
}
```

create a gridLayout at the size of the box table and where 2 is set to an image of a wall and 1 to an image of grass

then get an invisible tile and make a second gridlayout at the size of the first one. at the end you just have to set it over it with a JLayeredPane and replace invisibile tile by your character with cordinate given by the gridlayout.